# How to parse two different objects from the same json file?

Tags: java, android, json

How to parse two different objects from the same json file knowing that parsing one of them block parsing the other, which means that i have to parse only one of them, this is my code:

```
try {

            time  = json1.getJSONObject(TAG_TIME);
            String Time2 = time.toString();

            deals = json1.getJSONObject(TAG_DEALS);
            final String plusinfo = deals.getString(TAG_PLUS_INFO);
            String title = deals.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            Integer retail = deals.getInt(TAG_RETAIL);
            String  nretail = Integer.toString(retail);
            Integer deal = deals.getInt(TAG_DEAL);
            String  ndeal = Integer.toString(deal);
            String duration = deals.getString(TAG_DURATION);
            String image = deals.getString(TAG_IMAGE_URL);
            String participant = deals.getString(TAG_PARTICIPANT);
            final String details = deals.getString(TAG_DETAILS);
            final String name = deals.getString(TAG_ADVERTISER_NAME);
            final String adress = deals.getString(TAG_ADVERTISER_ADDRESS);
            final String phone = deals.getString(TAG_ADVERTISSER_PHONE);
            /*String Time1 = deals.getString(TAG_DATE);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date1 = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
            Date date2 = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
              try {  
                date1 = sdf.parse(Time1);
                date2 = sdf.parse(Time2);
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            final String precision = deals.getString(TAG_PRECISION);
            JSONArray c = deals.getJSONArray(TAG_PRECISION);
             ArrayList<String> arrays = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++){
                 precision = c.getString(i);
                 arrays.add(precision);

            }
             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_RETAIL, nretail);
            map.put(TAG_DEAL, ndeal);
            map.put(TAG_DURATION, duration);
            map.put(TAG_IMAGE_URL, image);
            map.put(TAG_PARTICIPANT, participant);
            map.put(TAG_SERVER_TIME, Time2);
            otherdeals.add(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it gets blocked? I dont see what the issue is with what you have posted. If you wish to parse two different JSON responses, either kick off two background threads (AsyncTask) or just parse them one after the other